# Making String private or public in Java

Tags: java, string, private, immutability, public

Strings in Java are said to be immutable. 
So if I say

```
String one = "myString";
```

and

```
String two = "myString";
```

Internally both the objects will be using the same literal.
Now what puzzlles me is why should I make my Strings private in different classes, when internally they will be referencing to the same string literal.

Is it just that external elements(like classes or object) will not know what members the class has inside it?

Comment: Well since they are immutable it does not matter if two members of two different objects point to the same object. But to prevent that anyone is changing the internal state of your object by reassigning a member variable, that is why you make it private.

Answer (score 1):

Visibility and access rights exists actually only during compilation, to check whether you're able to do this or that, during runtime generally you can call private methods or change immutable data via different hacks

Another point: these strings are immutable, so you cannot change their value via standard methods, so they can be the same place in memory and its doesnt matter which class uses them

Answer (score 0):

For `String` references, it doesn't really change anything. It's just a matter of convention and encapsulation. If your other fields are private and have getters and setters, why shouldn't your `String` fields (unless it's meant to be hidden)?

Comment: If I have public `getter` and `setter` then also I can change the reference to something else so whats the importance if private. And since internally they use the same string literal why shoul I make them private?

Comment: @Digvijay Yadiv You are the developer, so you don't necessarily have to implement a `setter` method if you don't want.  You can access it just with a `get` method. `getter` and `setters` are mandatory in pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Because the client could then set your internal members to something else entirely. It seems like you might be confusing a `String`'s being immutable with the reference being `final`.

Imagine you have this class:

```
public class MyClass {
    public String first = "Test";
    public String second = "Test";
}
```

So as Java compiler experts, we know internally `first` and `second` refer to the same object. Cool.

Now when I use `MyClass`:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.second = "Time to do some hackin'";
```

That's bad. Like real bad.

Declaring `String` members `private` has nothing to do with losing the advantage of compiler efficiencies. It is about the class encapsulating its implementation so that its clients aren't tightly coupled to it and so the class doesn't have to worry about weird behavior caused by something irresponsible the client did.

The fact that the object "Test" is immutable doesn't mean I can't change `first` or `second` to point to something else.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is exactly I am saying in the last line of my question. Since outer wolrd will not know about internal members, they won't be able to reassign anything. So is the reassigning is the only issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Using private for String reference blocks the direct access from outer objects. But setters and getters allow you to access/change the string variable (if you set). But in the setter method you can validate the parameters before changing the value. And that's the main advantage of using the setter method.

then, assume you have two equal private string variables in two objects. Then these two references should point to one place in the string pool. But that not sounds you can access both strings from one object (Because you always use reference variable that restricted by private modifier).